# Given functions such that $f = \tilde{f}$ and $g = \tilde{g}$, then $g\circ f = \tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f}$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Verify  the substitution property: if $f,\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g,\tilde{g}:Y\rightarrow Z$ are functions such that $f = \tilde{f}$ and $g = \tilde{g}$, then $g\circ f = \tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We say two functions $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are equal iff $f(x) = g(x)$, for all $x\in X$. Hence, for arbitrary values of $x\in X$, we have that
$$\begin{align}
(g\circ f)(x) &= g(f(x))\\
& = g(u) \\
&= \tilde{g}(u)\\
& = \tilde{g}(f(x)) \\
&= \tilde{g}(\tilde{f}(x)) \\
&= (\tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f})(x),
\end{align}$$
which proves that $g\circ f = \tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f}$.

Can someone check if I am reasoning rightly?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

However, be careful: here $g:Y\to Z$ is already given. It would help, instead, to write

> $h,k:A\to B$ are equal iff $h(a)=k(a)$ for all $a\in A$.

Stating that $u=f(x)$ is prudent too. In fact, you could do away with any such substitution, like so:

$$\begin{align}
(g\circ f)(x) &= g(f(x))\\
& = g(\tilde{f}(x)) \\
&= \tilde{g}(\tilde{f}(x)) \\
&= (\tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f})(x).
\end{align}$$